# How does sort() work for the sparse implementation of Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Some javascript implementations of Array switch to using a dictionary in case an array becomes sparse. How does sort() work in case the underlying structure switches to using a dictionary representation of Array ?

Comment: Surely that would depend on the specific underlying implementation? Or are you asking about what the effect of sorting a sparse array is from a purely JavaScript perspective (rather than the engine writers)?

Comment: @Quentin Basically, I wanted to know if it's better to copy a sparse array into a new dense one, and then sort it compared to sorting the sparse array itself. So I wanted to know if js implementations too copy the sparse (dictionary) implementation into a new array and then sort it, or it's something else.

Comment: You'd need to benchmark it yourself (I'd *guess* it depends on the number of `undefined` items in the array).